# Quality of photo being lost when Uploading to Firebase Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have tried

```
 if let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadImage, 0.9){
                let subFileName = NSUUID().uuidString
            storageRef.child("\(subFileName)").putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (data , error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!)
                }
            })
```

I have also tried

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation(uploadImage)
```

both of which do not produce the original quality image , the only thing that changes is the size in firebase storage... I have also tried changing the image with a cgSize change

```
 func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let size = image.size

    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height

    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio,  height: size.height * widthRatio)
    }

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

yet none of this has helped :( how can I fix this?

I know the image quality is bad because when I load it from download url in firebase console the quality is bad.. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I'm removing the Firebase tags because Firebase Storage will in no way alter the contents of anything uploaded to it, so it can't possibly be responsible for any loss in quality.

Comment: How do you produce `uploadImage`?  PNG is not lossy (and 0.9 is a high quality jpeg) so it seems more likely the problem is with the image rather than the encoding